# SQL Server CTE query isn't ordering the rows as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following CTE query and can't figure out why the rows aren't being ordered the way I expect. It's ordering the states then the counties. I'm trying to get the correct child county to appear after its parent state. So it should be Alabama, Autauga, Alaska, Aleutians East.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!!

[image: Table]

```
WITH Descendants AS 
(
    SELECT  
        p.Page, p.MetaDataID, 0 AS HLevel, p.ParentID, p.OrderNumber
    FROM 
        dbo.MetaData p
    WHERE 
        p.ParentID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        p.Page, p.MetaDataID, H.HLevel+1, p.ParentID, p.OrderNumber
    FROM 
        dbo.MetaData p
    INNER JOIN 
        Descendants H ON H.MetaDataID = p.ParentID  
)  
SELECT d.MetaDataID, d.[Page], d.ParentID
FROM Descendants d
ORDER BY d.OrderNumber, d.[Page]
```

[image]

Comment: You order by d.OrderNumber, a column which isn't in the select list (and not shown...), how can you tell the current result is in wrong order?

Comment: Because `ORDER BY d.OrderNumber`

Comment: You can be 100% sure `order by` works correctly. Your logic to get the column `OrderNumber` is probably wrong. Add that column to select to see what is returned. Maybe you need `h.OrderNumber` and not `p.OrderNumber` ?

Comment: I was trying to use OrderNUmber to sort the other pages (Default, Home, Map, State, County) but that is indeed what's causing the issue. If I remove the Order By altogether it's still not ordering them by parent/child

Answer (score -1):

Decided not to build the query as a parent/child. Thanks for the help